# Align div right to left with position properties on the right of the div

Tags: html, css

I like to place a `div`, where the position I state (here: `left: 20%`) is at the right of the div and not at the left. I already tried several things but everything failed. What do I have to do to archive this?

[image: The anchor challenge]

For the first two rows of this image I have the following CSS code, but I cannot get what I want for the third row.

```
<!-- Left orientated with anchor left -->
<div style="position: absolute;
            top: 20%;
            left: 20%;              
            ">
     <span>...</span>
</div>

<!-- Right orientated with anchor left but right to left flow -->      
<div style="position: absolute;
            top: 30%;
            left: 20%;
            direction: rtl;             
            ">
     <span>...</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="wrap" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; display: inline-table; border: 1px dashed #aaa;">
        <div style="position: relative;
                    display: table-cell;
                    border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
                    width: 20%;   
                    ">
             <span>1</span>
        </div>

        <div style="position: relative
                    top: 30%;
                    display: table-cell;
                    width: 80%;
                    direction: rtl;             
                    ">      
                <div style="position: relative
                            top: 30%;
                            width: 50%;
                            text-align: left;
                            display: table-cell;
                            float: left;         
                            ">2.1<span> 2.2</span>

                </div>
                <div style="position: relative
                            top: 30%;
                            text-align: left;
                            width: 50%;
                            display: table-cell;
                            float: right;        
                            ">3.1<span> 3.2</span>

                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: That was a fast answer. The `position: relative;` was the key

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. You need to have everything in one row, right?